# Google Sheets - Arrayformula with textjoin, and, if

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to figure out how to make my arrayformula with textjoin to work, but the formula does not copy to another row.

[image]

I want the job no automatically generate when i write data in F3 cell & G3 cells.
But i having problem the formula does not automatically inserted to I3.

My formula looks as following right now:

=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(ISBLANK(F2),ISBLANK(G2))," ",TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,LEFT(F2,4)&ROW()-1,RIGHT(G2,2))))

Any Google Sheets pro's out there who could help me out in a direction?

Would be thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `textjoin()` and `and()` are aggregating functions so they do not work the way you seem to expect in an array formula context.

To make it work, use the concatenation operator `&` and boolean multiplication, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(F2:F) * len(G2:G), 
    left(F2:F, 4) & sequence(rows(F2:F)) & "-" & right(G2:G, 2), 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

To evaluate an array formula over a range, you need to use multi-cell range references instead of single-cell references. The formula above uses open-ended range references like `F2:F` to evaluate all the way to the bottom of the sheet.

Since the formula fills all of the column from row 2 down, you must place it in row 2 of a column where there are no values or formulas from row 2 down.

Comment: Thank you so much, you really help me a lot, I have try the formula and it's work like charm. I'm new to this, so many things need to learn. Thank you for explaining it to me